# How to make an exclusion for some url when redirectiong to https://www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, web, https

I`m using .htaccess to redirect all queries to https:// www. example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#and below some rules from symfony2 configuration

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

And now I want to make exclusion for some url: http:// example.com/someurl
(not to redirect this url to https scheme and not to add www) How can I get this?

I was looking for answer in stackoverflow, but solutions were found for only one rule when redirecting to https...

Comment: take a look at the S flag of RewriteRule https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exclusions using `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/someurl [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/someurl [NC]
RewriteRule textriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#and below some rules from symfony2 configuration

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```